# Db2 pureScale CF is periodically restarted with the "CF process group file read but process group IDs are invalid" message

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Db2 11.1.4.6, AIX, 2 members + 2 CFs.

Db2 pureScale CF is periodically restarted with the following message in the CF's db2diag.log:

```
                                                    LEVEL: Warning
PID     : xxx                  TID : 1              PROC : db2rocme 128 [db2sdin1]
INSTANCE: db2sdin1             NODE : 128
HOSTNAME: cf128
EDUID   : 1                    EDUNAME: db2rocme 128 [db2sdin1]
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, high avail services, rocmCAKillProcesses, probe:4299
MESSAGE : CF process group file read but process group IDs are invalid -
          attempting to force stop.
DATA #1 : Codepath, 8 bytes
1:7:16
```

I have the following, for example, when it works normally:

```
# ps -ef -o pid,ppid,pgid,args | grep -v grep | grep db2
 8454558        1  8388876 ca-wdog 128 [db2sdin1]
15401326 17891750  8388876 /home/db2sdin1/sqllib/cf/ca-server -i 128 -p 56000 -k 333448195 -s 0 -r 131073031 -f
17891750  8454558  8388876 ca-mgmnt-lwd -i128 -p56000 -ke32e317a -d/home/db2sdin1/sqllib/db2dump/DIAG0128 -e/home/db2sdin1/sqllib/cf/ca-server -f
```

What's the problem and how to resole it?

Comment: Have you noticed anything weird with the process group id when it happens?

Comment: I even don't have any idea what is normal or what is weird with this. It's not clear from this message what's the "problematic" process which process group is invalid. I've edited the question to show the "normal" situation...

Comment: What (third party) packages are running on the same lpar as the cf? Anything in the AIX system message log immediately before the timestamp of the cf restarting?   Presumably you already opened a ticket with ibm db2 support?

Comment: Nothing third party is running that would change a db2 process group id. Nothing appears in the AIX syslog.

Comment: Is it LDAP that is managing the users/groups for both CFs, or what is it that keeps them in sync?

Comment: All the users are local with the same uids and gids of course.

Comment: IS there a non-prod similar environment, on which you can experiment? Is there any pattern to the symptom frequency of occurrence? Does DIAGLEVEL 4 show any more detail? I suspect that the small number of multisite pureScale implementations globally  might mean that IBM db2 support is your only option (unless you have a non-prod equivalent on which to experiment).